# Graph representation in Java using linked structure

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I need to implement a graph in Java.  I cannot use the collection classes.  I can readily create a graph using an Adjacency Matrix or an Adjacency List, but I need to create a directed graph using a linked structure.

I might be given the adjacency matrix form:

```
4           // square matrix size -- all would be square -- square only   
0 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1
```

NOTE:  This is supposed to a a 4x4 matrix, but I cannot format correctly for StackOverflow.  I do not know how to enter hard return.

Continuing my question, I found a similar question on StackOverflow:

[Questions regarding Implementation of graph in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567609/questions-regarding-implementation-of-graph-in-c)

Where in the best accepted answer, pmr wrote:

1.) Yes, you can also implement it explicitly using pointers to other nodes.

This answer by pmr is the form of solution I need.  This is where I am having trouble.  I simply cannot picture this solution in my head.  One of the problems is how do I allow for a number of child nodes that is read from a file so that I can refer to them for a search ?  One adjacency list implementation would allow me to create an array of linked lists, but I cannot use that.

Is this a multi-graph ?  Is this a problem that multi-graphs solve ?

Alternate: I have also envisioned a tree structure with multiple child nodes per parent.

How would I go about implementing this in Java ?

Comment: Are you allowed to implement your own linked list, as opposed to using the built in in Java?

Comment: Yes, I do have a Linked List implementation that I can use. I created it myself and will suffice for now.  It is working, tested,  and debugged.

Comment: Are you going to have to traverse the graph?

Comment: Anyways. Implementation, you need to be able to add edges, remove edges, get how many vertices you have and that sort of functionality. Linked Lists are a chain, I don't know if it's entirely appropriate for this.

Comment: A linked list would work if your graph was a line of nodes, but it isn't, it's a square of nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

Create a class representing each graph node.

```
class GraphNode {
   LinkedList<GraphNode> children;
}
```

Each line of data you read in will represent a GraphNode. Each '1' in that line represents a link to the GraphNode at the same index as that '1'.

Create a GraphNode for each line and add it to a list/array of GraphNodes (maybe call it 'allNodes'). For each 1 or 0 on a line, increment a counter. If it is a 1, add the Node in allNodes at that index (use counter as the index) to the children of the current node.

Now you will have a list of GraphNodes, each with its own list of the GraphNodes it is connected to.

Hope that makes sense.